# Plesk: Overriding httpd.conf SSLCertificateFile via vhost_ssl.conf?

Tags: apache, ssl, httpd.conf, plesk, vhosts

I am running a virtual server (Ubunto, Plesk 12). For the vhosts the settings are stored in httpd.conf, which is generated by Plesk.

When having activated SSL-Support in Plesk, then Plesks default certificate is referenced, even when no certificate has been selected. Trying to override this value via vhost_ssl.conf results in Apache not being able to start/ restart. My tech support told me, that Apache is trying to bind both certificates then, instead of overriding the SSLCertificateFile directive.

When having SSL-Support deactivated in Plesk, then all directives regarding SSL (< IfModule mod_ssl.c >) are missing in httpd.conf. I guess additional directives within vhost_ssl.conf wont work then.

Is there any other way to replace/ override the default certificate? It is no option to put the setting into httpd.conf directly (iE via VI), because once I make a change in Plesk related to this file, it is overwritten. It is also no option, to put the certificates keys into Plesk, because they need to be updated regulary and I dont want to do that manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your certificate for domain if you upload certificate to subscription's repository here:

[image]

Also you can try LetsEncrypt extension from Extensions Catalog.

By the way, Plesk's LetsEncrypt extension updates all it's certificates by cron task every month:

[image]

Comment: I am aware of this, but this way I need to update the certificate manually. Up to now, the extension doesnt feature this.

Comment: Plesk's LetsEncrypt extension creates cron task in Plesk for each certificate to automatically update certificate one time in month.

Comment: You can find and manage Let's Encrypt extension task in Tools&Settings > Scheduled Tasks.